# t-Test = intersection between two distributions?

Tags: t-test

Is it correct that the p-value of the t-Test is equal to the intersection between two normal distributions?

$\Rightarrow p\text{-value} = \frac{\textit{intersection between N1 and N2}}{\textit{union between N1 and N2}}$

[image: intersection between two normal distributions]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "targets"?

Comment: I'd like to know if the idea of the t-test is to test if the proportion covered by the blue area is smaller than $\alpha$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not familiar with any such formulation. The t test provides an assessment of the probability of observing a point estimate (sample mean) under some null hypothesis or reference. If the left distribution on your plot is the reference or H0, the p value is the probability of observing the sample mean of the red point or greater under H0. The more extreme the point, the less likely it was generated by the process generating H0.

The fact that it’s t- rather than z- (normal) respects the fact that you have a sample, and as such the distributions are sensitive to sample size

Comment: Thank you for your description.
I remember a statistics course where the p-value was described as the proportion of the intersection area of two distributions, but I wasn't sure if this applies to the t-Test as well.

Comment: It’s the proportion of the reference t distribution falling at or greater than your test point (if a one-tailed test)